# ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation

Tags: support, stack-snippets

While I was researching in order to answer a question on Stack Oveflow en español, I decided to try the code on https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition<sup>1</sup>.

But I got the following error

> Warning: ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation

I think that Google Chrome is considering the stack snippet as insecure. See 
[Geolocation API Removed from Unsecured Origins in Chrome 50](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only). Is there something that as end-user I could do to make this work?

> <sup>1</sup> The referred link was the original source of the referenced code. If you need the English version see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition but bear in mind that the Mozilla Developer Network docs are edited by the community and some language versions are not direct translations of another.

```js
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Related posts

- Stack Overflow en Español

  - [ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81291/65)
  - [Error en Geocolización asp.net app google maps](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81278/65)

Comment: Shouldn't that rather go to Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: The stack snippet feature is available on several sites of the network, not only on [so], by the other hand here we have a tag about stack snippets :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it can live here.

Comment: @Shadow I think that references to the source of the code I took should **not** be edited.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the link on the note, but not the reference to the original source.

Comment: @Rubén yes they should. On this site we should use only English, not Spanish, since most people who browse the site do not understand Spanish. If you want to link to Spanish sites, do it on the per-site meta of Spanish SE sites. I did not change any of the code, just linked to the generic page, not its Spanish version.

Comment: All the required info about this issue is in English. I also included a link to the English version.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get you. I checked now twice. **The code is the same in both versions**, one just use Spanish to explain and the other English. I don't see what is your problem then.

Comment: Good to know that you take the time to check that the code is the same in both versions. Not on all MDN docs occurs that, by the other hand, I don't see how that edit make the post clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question on Stack Overflow en español got an [answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81354/65). The most relevant part is that Stack Snippet is blocking the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) due to the lack of `allow-same-origin` flag on the sandbox attribute of the iframe used to embed Stack Snippets.

As end-user as a workaround we could add the flag manually or by writing a command on the browser console or to use another service like JSFiddle.

IMHO, a feature request should be made.